# How to iterate over a list of suffixes to add to the end of each variable in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

What I'm trying to do is optimize my current code that uses dataframes. The dataframes follow a similar naming convention, so instead of explicitly naming them, I'm trying to create them on the fly and then process them.

```
days = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
#1,2,3,4,5 are dataframes
endings = ['_operation1', '_operation2']
suffixedFrames = [x.add_suffix(y) for x, y in zip(days, endings)]
print(suffixedFrames)
```

The problem is that when I run this, it only prints out two dataframes, specifically, 1_operation1 and 1_operation2. How do I make it add the suffix to every dataframe in list days?

Comment: as it stands if I cut & paste your code it doesnt work. That aside your problem is that `endings` needs to be twice as long as `days` to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip does not work as you want to, but it creates an iterator of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element of the 2 list you're using, as you can see [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). In your case if you do `print(list(zip(days, endings)))` you will see this:

`[(1, '_operation1'), (2, '_operation2')]`.

In order to achieve what you want you can do as follows:

```
import itertools
days = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
#1,2,3,4,5 are dataframes
endings = ['_operation1', '_operation2']
suffixedFrames = [x.add_suffix(y) for x, y in list(itertools.product(days, endings))]
print(suffixedFrames)
```

Comment: can I refer to the items in the list as 1_operation1, 1_operation2,.,?

Comment: @MatthiasTom the result I've provided in the answer is a list. If you want to reference something with a string, you can use a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) to create a dictionary with the desired string as key, and `x.add_suffix(y)` as value. For example:  
`{x.columns[0] + y: x.add_suffix(y) for x, y in list(itertools.product(days, endings))}`